# How can I get the value of a radio button inside a google visualization table

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

I have a table that I build using a chart wrapper as follows:

```
var rightWrapper;
function drawVisualization() {
  rightWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  "chartType": "Table",
  'dataSourceUrl':'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3N5DtdXGWFootaOCQM201K_ao2ZPWSWyw9_l7QcwQg/gviz/tq?sheet=User_my_crew&headers=1',
  'containerId':'target_table_div',
  'query':'SELECT A,B,C,D',
  'options': { 'width': 700, 'height': 500, 'allowHtml': true }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(rightWrapper, 'ready', onRightReady);

  rightWrapper.draw();

  function onRightReady() {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(rightWrapper.getChart(), 'select', rightSelectionHandler);
  }

  function rightSelectionHandler() {
    var selection = rightWrapper.getChart().getSelection();
    if (selection.length == 1) {
      var item = selection[0];
      if (item.row != null) {
        alert("selected row " + item.row);
        var value = (rightWrapper.getSnapshot().getDataTable().getValue(item.row,3));
        alert(value);
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

And in that column 3, I have html to build radio buttons.  Unfortunately, the actual html is stored, and I don't seem to have a way of polling to find out which radio button is now checked (the getValue listed in the code above always shows me just the html that was used to build the radio buttons, not which one is now "checked").

Unfortunately, it appears any clicks inside that table have to be picked up with the select listener, and the select listener doesn't relay any information beyond the row and column selected.  I tried building in change and click functions, and putting s around my radio buttons, too.  For instance:

```
$("#radio").click(function(){  //also tried with .change
  alert("working");
});
```

That never fires, even if I disable my original listener.

So, how can I know what radio button my user selected?

Note: I do need the radio buttons inside the table, as every single row of the table has its own radio buttons to provide me different information on each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the form, you just need to wait for the chart's `'ready'` event,
before assigning the change event.

see following working snippet,
select a radio to see the name and value...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var rightWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3N5DtdXGWFootaOCQM201K_ao2ZPWSWyw9_l7QcwQg/gviz/tq?sheet=User_my_crew&headers=1',
    containerId: 'target_table_div',
    query: 'SELECT A,B,C,D',
    options: { 'width': 700, 'height': 500, 'allowHtml': true }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(rightWrapper, 'ready', onRightReady);

  rightWrapper.draw();

  function onRightReady() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', calcForm2);
  }
});

function calcForm2(sender) {
  console.log(sender.target.name, sender.target.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="target_table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Not sure why I didn't try that before.

Comment: Hmm... one challenge on this is that from inside the function I don't seem to be able to call calcForm2 or call google.run.script, which is required (I believe) to update my source database.

Comment: hmm.. I added an alert to calcForm2 to see that it's there, and it's clearly there and passing the object over to it, but... it's still not calling the google run script

Comment: Ah... It works now. I don't know why, but for some reason it didn't like passing the new object.  I changed it to: google.script.run.calcForm(sender.target.name,sender.target.value);

Comment: hmm... any idea why sorting the table would cause that listener to break?

Comment: yes, the chart is cleared then re-drawn, so all the radios are destroyed and re-created, need to reapply the change event  -- use `'sort'` event, similar to `'ready'` event...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out something that works

I can add a form around my radio buttons with the event.preventdefault code and call a function:

```
<form name="myForm" onchange="event.preventDefault(); calcForm2(this);">...radiobuttons...</form>
```

Then in my function I do whatever I want with "this".  It comes across as "name=value" so it's pretty easy to split and parse.